# Laguerre transform function

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

For continuous indices 'n' and 'm' is it possible to have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dx e^{-x}L_{n}(x)L_{m}(x) = \delta (n-m)? $$

Another question: let $g(m)$ be the function defined via the transform

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dx e^{-x}f(x)L_{m}(x)=g(m). $$

Is its inverse given by $$  \int_{0}^{\infty}dm e^{-m}g(m)L_{m}(x)=f(x), $$

so that $$  \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-m}dm\int_{0}^{\infty}dx e^{-x}L_{n}(x)L_{m}(x) =1? $$

to be more explicit , let be the integral transform

$$ g(m)= \int_{0}^{\infty}dxe^{-x}f(x)L_{m}(x) $$ , then how could we obtain $ f(x) $ from $ g(m) $ ??

Comment: By $\delta(n-m)$ do you mean a Dirac delta? If so that isn't true since we know that the integral is equal to a finite value when $n=m$. That aside this is an interesting idea, do you have a definition for what $L_{m}(x)$ means for non-integer values? Maybe we can modify the recurrence realtions to make this work.

Comment: Non integer index reminds me of scattering states of a quantum mechanical system..

Comment: By any chance, were you talking about the q-Laguerre polynomials?

Comment: Thats true, an interesting difference is that while the scattering aren't normalizable these are (If you consider $L_m e^{-x/2}$ to be the "state" in question).

Comment: @Spencer Yeah.We must also keep measures in our mind. But I think the OP is actually talking about the quantum-laguerre polynomials [here](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/MASCOS/Orthogonal09/Warnaar.pdf‎)

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu your link doesn't work.

Comment: I think I cant edit for another 5 minutes, anyway, it looks broken now. You can google/wiki for it however.

Comment: for non integer 'm' we can use fractional derivative to define $ L_{m}(x)= \frac{e^{x}}{\Gamma (m+1)}D_{x}^{n}(x^{n}e^{-x}) $